# Awesome wm slow when switching tabs

Tags: awesome-wm

I have a fresh install with awesome wm on debian testing.

I have installed the proprietary ATI drivers, and compton.

The problem is that there is a 1~2 second delay when switching between tabs if one or both of them contains an open window (like Iceweasel). How can I fix this to make the switching as fast as it ought to be?

I'm sure my system is able to handle it, my specs:

- AMD FX 8120 8x 3.1ghz
- 8gb ram
- OZC 60gb SSD
- ATI radeon HD 6970

Comment: Are you using the default configuration or you have edit it? If so, have you change something related to the tabs?

Comment: @Just1602 I haven't touched the configuration files yet.

Comment: If you lauch top or htop if installed, have you something that take a lot of memoery/CPU?

You can also install mesa-utils and run glxgears to see if you graphic card work well.